# Why Using the JobScheduler API?

Tags: android

What is JobScheduler ? which type of android apps using this JobScheduler and why ? Please feedback with real example so that I could understand.

Comment: Why not using Google to search for an answer to such a question?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short summary:

1) AlarmManager.- Use it to post a notification or set off an alarm at a very specific time. Use this for executions that do not depend on condition.

2) JobScheduler.- Allows you to have execute jobs based on conditions.  This is recommended if your app targets API>21.

3) JobDispatcher.- Similar behavior as JobScheduler, used as a JobScheduler-compatibility layer if your app targets versions lower than API<21.  Note that this needs internet for real time execution, any task not executed because of internet not being available will be executed when internet becomes available.